# Set text input field display value different from actual value

Tags: javascript, angular

Example:

```
const obj = {name:"abc", value:"20"};
```

Have to set the value as 20, but to display to the user abc.

Comment: Did you try a `hidden` field for the value? Or a `select`?

Comment: No the field Is not hidden it is type ="text"

Comment: You could insert `20` into a `hidden` field and display `abc` next to it.

Comment: Next to it?   "abc" should be it in the text field but as I submit the value I should get 20

Comment: @NehaSingh angular Version? and it would be better if you add your try in the question or expected output!

Comment: Angular version :Angular 5

Comment: @NehaSingh have a check here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sk6v8a Is that what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `select` menu:

```
<select>
    <option value="20">abc</option>
    <option value="100">xyz</option>
</select>
```

Then the user can choose **abc**, but the value you get is **20**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to post to the server the same data that the user sees. With Angular, you can keep data structures that are independent of the view and send those to the server.

For example, you could define a Product interface like this:

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
  category: string;
  categoryId: number;
}
```

The user interface could allow display/entry of a category, but the data structure could retain the value as a categoryId. You could then pass only the categoryId back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is what you see and another one is what you send. Some like (it's a silly example)

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input [(ngModel)]="user">
</form>

const obj = [{name:"abc", value:"20"},{name:"def", value:"30"}];
user:any;
ngOnInit()
{
     this.user=dataToForm(20);
}
onSubmit()
{
   let data=this.formToData(this.user);
   console.log(data);
}

//we received real data and transform to display data
dataToForm(data:any)
{
   let item=obj.find(x=>x.value==data);
   return item?item.name:null
}

//we received display data and transform to real data
formToData(dataForm:any)
{
   let item=obj.find(x=>x.name==dataForm);
   return item?item.value:null

}
```